# Legend names in bar chart in shiny app not showing

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to find out the reason why the legend names are not showing for bar chart.

The legend names should be shown as the row names. But it is showing in numbers.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
bld <- read.csv("C:/Users/velumani_d/Documents/My Dashboard/BLD.csv")
bldr <- rownames(bld)
bldn <- nrow(bld)

ui<- shinyUI(dashboardPage(dashboardBody(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Block Level"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Visitors", "Select column name:", choices = 
colnames(bld)), hr(), helpText("Data from DESH")),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("Bar_chart"))
  )
))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
output$Bar_chart <-  renderPlot({
        barplot(bld[,input$Visitors], main = input$Suspected, ylab="No of 
visitors", xlab = "Blocks", legend = bldr, beside = FALSE, col = 1:bldn)
})
    })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

dataset:

```
Block      Visitors Suspected
Amingaon    75      40
Azara       68      23
Chaygaon    80      30
Hajo        728     200
Kamalpur    1814    500
N.Guwahati  529     250
Rangia      49      24
Sualkuchi   1534    400
```

[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UImK3.png)

Comment: Probably the rownames are just numbers from `1:nrow(bld)`. Make sure that is not the case and also share `bld` dataframe if possible for further help.

Comment: Here is the bld dataframe: Block Visitors Suspected
Amingaon 75 40
Azara 68 23
Chaygaon 80 30
Hajo 728 200
Kamalpur 1814 500
N.Guwahati 529 250
Rangia 49 24
Sualkuchi 1534 400